# How to create a trigger on user_scheduler_jobs in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am new to oracle. In our application, we need to execute a procedure when the run duration of a scheduled job exceeds 10 minutes. We are checking in `user_scheduler_jobs` table and have to fire a procedure when the `last_run_duration` column exceeds 10 minutes. We tried to create a trigger for this purpose as shown below :

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG1
  AFTER UPDATE ON ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS
  BEGIN
  MONITOR_JOB_DURATION();
  END TRG1;
```

But when I try to compile the trigger it is showing an error as

```
Error report:
ORA-25001: cannot create this trigger type on views
25001. 00000 -  "cannot create this trigger type on views"
*Cause:    Only INSTEAD OF triggers can be created on a view.
*Action:   Change the trigger type to INSTEAD OF.
```

Is `user_scheduler_jobs` a view? 
If I proceed with `INSTEAD OF` trigger, will it effect the updation which is automatically happening after job execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is to check in your code how long something has been running and then do something. As [APC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567313/458741) says on no account start putting triggers or anything else in the SYS schema, you'll cause more trouble that it's worth. Something like the below should work:

```
declare

   l_start_time date default sysdate;

   -- other stuff

begin

  -- do something

  if sysdate - l_start_time > ( 1 / 24 / 6 )
     -- run something else
     -- maybe using dbms_scheduler
  end if;

  -- do more stuff

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `user_scheduler_jobs` a view?   It surely is.  What's more, it is in the SYS schema and you really should not be attempting to mess with that schema.  It is crucial to the running of your database and it should be kept exactly as Oracle installs it.

---

Oracle Enterprise Manager has some functionality to monitor jobs.  Did you  look at that before embarking on rolling your own?

Comment: +1, most definitely; altering sys is the surest way to cause problems.

Comment: Sorry to say that I don't know anything about Oracle Enterprise Manager. I will try to look into that. Thank you for your valuable information.